# Along/down the street

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between:
He was walking **along** the street,
and
He was walking **down** the street ?

Comment: "along" could easily mean parallel to... or on the side of the road. "down" to me would mean that they are physically _on_ the road itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Up my street and down the lane](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83597/up-my-street-and-down-the-lane)

Comment: @d'alar'cop: I don't think so. That would be *alongside* the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually both expression mean the same: a continuous movement on the road. In "along" is contained "long", so one may guess the idea is "(on) the length of the road" or in "along the river" "(on) the length beside the river". A verb of movement + down normally describes a mouvent from a higher point to a lower point. But it is also used for horizontal movement.