# What are "up" and "down" in "up there" and "down there"?

Tags: prepositions, expressions, word-usage, prepositional-phrases

*"Up there"* and *"down there"* are two of the most frequent expressions that I, myself, use often.  I really don't know whether they are just expressions used to refer to a place to go *("I went **down** there and picked up the mail")* or whether they have some significance attached to them. Like recently at the airport, somebody told me *"to go **down** there for the International terminal"* and I wondered whether they meant "down" literally, or was it just the expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prepositions are often interchangeable in English, even when they seem to mean exactly the opposite thing in their literal sense. It is possible, for example, to say

> You'll find a Chevron station **down** the road about five miles.

or

> You'll find a Chevron station **up** the road about five miles.

or even

> You'll find a Chevron station **along** the road about five miles.

and mean exactly the same place.

When someone tells you to go "down there for the International Terminal" they don't necessarily mean literally *down* as in on another vertical level *unless the terminal happens to be on another vertical level*. They could probably just as easily have said "up there for the International Terminal" — or even "*over* there for the International Terminal."

Prepositions may also be used as mild intensifiers. Instead of saying "Get out of here," someone might colloquially add emphasis with a few supererogatory prepositions: "Get on up out of here." Paradoxically, those same prepositions could be used to *soften* the statement as well. Much depends on context and tone.

Comment: Sometimes I might be more inclined to use _up_ instead of _down_ in a particular situation, e.g. I might say _up_ if I'm going _north_, or _down_ when I'm travelling _south_ (particularly when the distances are long). As another example, on a river, _up_ is against the current, and _down_ is with the current. That said, more often than not, I could use _up_, _down_, or _out_ just about interchangeably, as in, _"We're going to drive up/down/out to Uncle Dave's for Christmas."_

Comment: @J.R.: In the UK many people still speak of going [up to London](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/) even if that means travelling *South*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Same here. We might be more inclined to use _up_ for _north_ and _down_ for _south_, but that's only a generality, and exceptions abound.

Comment: @J.R.: I'd say _up river_ is almost always towards the source; tidal rivers change direction of flow. The really tricky ones are the two-way rivers (eg Katonga, Kafu) and those that reverse flow (eg Tonlé Sap).

Answer (score 5):

As any good dictionary will show you, *up* and *down* both have many meanings beyond those related to location in a vertical plane. When someone gives a direction such as the one you mention, the words are usually accompanied by a gesture or a movement of the head which should remove any doubt about what is meant.

Comment: Without delving too much into the word-classes _up_ and _down_ are claimed to flit through, I think most people would concede their prepositional usage/s. The 'prototypical' use of prepositions is to show relations in the physical world, which usage can be termed _semantic_: the station is down the road / he went down the road. In these examples, _down_ obviously also syntactically joins the subject to the words expressing location or direction. This syntactic property is exploited in constructions dealing with non-spatial relationships: on the train --> on the hour --> on fire --> on ice.

Comment: @Barrie yes she did gesture towards the terminal, but there was down elevator also there, that led to the confusion