# Why do people say "Go down this road" or "Go down this corridor" instead of saying "Go straight"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs, speech, modifiers

I was wondering, when giving directions, is it correct to say "go straight" instead of "go down"? Does down and straight in the context of giving directions mean the same thing?

Comment: Why indeed? "Go that way, It's up here, Across this junction, etc.* It's all a matter of opinion and circumstance/context. Metaphoric spatial references are a standard feature of English, but [this was one earlier ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92881/) on the matter.

Comment: They say these things because they mean to say "Go down this road" or "Go down this corridor."

Comment: Because that's what people say.  If you wish to say "go straight" then that's fine too.

Comment: Imagine if they said, "Just go straight down this road..."

Comment: Go *straight* means don't take any turns onto other roads, and usually works best when the road you're on is pretty straight too.

Comment: Using *down* idiomatically in *go down* is a common trait in many languages. Therefore, this not a question just about the English language. It is about the propensity of humankind to say "go down".

Comment: 'Down' is particularly used as 'towards the centre', as in 'downtown'.  I guess this might have started because most old towns and cities were built beside, or on either side of, a river, so it really *was* down to the centre.

Comment: The "why" part of the question hinges around two assumptions: 1) that the word "down" has an intrinsic meaning and 2) that it can have only one meaning at most. Neither assumption is true of *any* word in *any* language. In fact, no word in and of itself has any meaning at all. It means whatever people want it to mean. You have to use *some* word. And "down" *is* a word. As long as we all agree on it, everything's fine. If we all agreed to say "go cat" instead, then we'd use that one. If we all use "go orange", then that's what you get.

Comment: There's a straightforward grammatical answer to this question - and it is not opinion based!!! It is about the grammar of prepositions. *THIS QUESTION SHOULD NOT HAVE BEEN CLOSED!!*

Comment: [Nobody cares which one *you* prefer.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/nobody-cares-how-you-pronounce-it) Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go down the corridor

Does not actually imply going straight, it may mean navigating corners or bends, much like:

> Follow the corridor.

If someone says:

> Go straight...

They usually mean it literally, avoiding any turns or corners.