# He was running down the dusty track through the centre of town

Tags: meaning-in-context

"He was running down the dusty track through the centre of town"

What does "running down" mean in this sentence? Does it mean that he was running downwards?

And, what does this sentence try to imply by saying that that he was running down through the centre of the town? What does "through the centre of town" mean here? Does this mean that he was running from the centre of town?

Comment: Running down = running along.  The track went through the center of town.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are "up" and "down" in "up there" and "down there"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92881/what-are-up-and-down-in-up-there-and-down-there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Down' here means 'along', it doesn't imply downward direction. 'Through the centre' means he's probably in the very midst of the central area, crossing it. Hope it helps!