# Does "coming down" mean "traveling south"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

In the context of traveling, I have heard of and used the phrase "coming down" when referring to a journey from one place to another place that is further south. Perhaps, it's because I have always related the "down" part to "from north to south".
For example:

> My cousin in New York is coming down to visit me (in Atlanta) next
>   week.

Recently, a friend of mine used the phrase to refer to any journey regardless of the direction of travel.
For example:

> She is coming down from Miami to join us in Atlanta.

Is the phrase used only to refer to traveling south? Or is it not related to the direction?

Comment: Related question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/do-i-travel-up-or-down-to-london-from-north-of-the-city).

Comment: @Brian Hooper: I think it's basically the same question. Closevoting as a dup. Of course, you can reasonably go ***up** to Oxford* even if you live north of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it is not a dupe. That is only about London, not about English in general.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree. The other question relates specifically to "going up/down to London", which has it's own specific terminology in some instances, as mentioned in the question. I was taught that one always goes *up* to London, wherever in England you start from.

Comment: @TrevorD: I think you had a peculiarly opinionated teacher. You *tend* to go "up" to places which are bigger, more northerly, or simply at a higher elevation. But no such usage is consistent enough to be something that ought to be "taught". And as regards whether it's a dup or not, most of the answers to the earlier question address the general case, not just London.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I really do think the general usage is a mapwise one that reflects our current habit of orienting our maps such that the cardinal direction north is in the “up” direction. Portuguese is interesting because it has verbs both for *orientar(-se)* and also for *nortear*.

Comment: @tchrist: Any one individual's opinion is likely to be highly skewed by their personal circumstances. People go **up, down** or **into** town if they live in the suburbs, and local geography or idiomatic preference may be far more important than compass directions. All possible influences are just *tendencies*. A Welsh friend of mine always speaks of coming **up** to visit me, despite the fact that she lives slightly further **north** than me (near Cardiff). That's because I live within 20 miles of London, and she always thinks you go ***up** to London* from Wales.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Cardiff is up from Bristol, sure, but from London, dunno: the east–west component should dominate. But really, in North America up/down is always north/south if you live in the flatlands; only if you live in the mountains is it actually up and down, and sometimes not even then. Honest! Ask anybody.

Comment: @tchrist: But that's my whole point - she doesn't actually *go* to London! But just because from her perspective I'm *close* to London, that's what determines her usage (completely overriding both compass direction *and* the fact that she lives at a considerably higher elevation above sea level than me). She effectively makes her choice of preposition "by proxy", since it's not *directly* justified by any rationales covered so far. (Or maybe she just thinks I live in a more "up-market" house, I don't really know! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, 3 of the answers in the other question support me! But I do agree that the usage may be dying out, or possibly peculiar to the S.E.? I live south of London anyway, so it's also *up* in the sense of going north!

Comment: @TrevorD: I'm also south (we could be close neighbours!), but many decades ago my girlfriend's parents lived in Rickmansworth (just north), and they used to go *up* to London. I'm not going to go analysing and counting *all* the answers on the earlier question, but I think the top-voted one somewhat specifically addresses the special case of ***up/down trains***. And at a cursory glance many of the rest seem to support my assertion that any principle of usage here is at best a *tendency*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally going down refers to travelling south, just as going up normally refers to travelling north.  That’s why it’s called [Upstate New York](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstate_New_York): because it is *north* of the core metro area.  That’s what makes it up: the north part. It almost always works this way.

Almost — but not always. When you live in the mountains, these things take on a more literal meaning, because altitude’s Z-axis is a lot more important there than the X- and Y-axes of longitude and latitude.

For example, if I go up to Nederland Colorado from down in Boulder — which is something people say and do all the time — that means travelling **west** from here, **not** travelling south.  It’s also 3,000 thousand feet higher, which is   all that counts in these parts.  It’s up because it’s, um, up.

But flatlanders, lacking a significant Z-axis, always use up and down to correspond to north and south.  (They forget the times when maps were ***oriented*** to the east. :)

For a completely different take on *up*, see the [Uptown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uptown) of various cities.

Comment: On Long Island in New York, traveling from the Eastern End to the west (actually WSW), you are said to be going *up island* (accompanied by a mild sneer).  There is a similar configuration on Martha's Vineyard in Massachusetts. This may be based on the concept of *going **down** to the sea*.  In both of these cases, the seafaring communities are on the extreme east ends (including the norther parts of those east ends).

Comment: Don't forget about the Upper and Lower Nile. That always confused me. And of course, the Devil went down to Georgia, which could be understood to mean south or in terms of elevation (down to the underworld).

Answer (score 0):

What "*comes down*" to my mind when I read "*to come down*" is **something descending from above** ("up and down"), instead of "north and south". Therefore, I think it's just a colloquial expression when used in a context of travel. (It does not literally means "*to go to the south*").

Comment: It may be worth noting, however, that the phrases "go down" and "go up" _do_ generally indicate direction. A U.S. resident, for example, would typically speak of "going up to Toronto" or "going down to Mexico," but not vice versa.

Comment: So, what is your interpretation of it in the context of travel? Is it air travel because an airplane "descends from above"?

Comment: One could "go up to Toronto by using an Airplane", or could "go up to the sky by using an Airplane". I think that the first one is more "colloquial" and less literal.

Comment: @pvn: Tempting as that etymology may sound, the phrase actually antedates air travel by more than two centuries. See, for example, its use in the diary of Samuel Pepys on [26 June 1661](http://www.pepysdiary.com/diary/1661/06/).

Comment: Hey how come in Portuguese only *orientar* and *nortear* exist, but no *sulear* or *ocidentar*? :)

Comment: I have no idea haha, we don't even use these two verbs. But you're right, there's no "sulear" or "ocidentar", and it does not make any sense. Actually, we use the verb "orientar", but in the sense of "to guide".