# "all the way down to" phrase with geographical locations

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Is the following usage correct:

> I drove from Los Angeles **all the way down** to San Diego.

given that San Diego is at the south of Los Angeles? Can it be used for geographical directions?

Comment: Certainly. Doubtless John Lawler would say something akin to 'This is an example of the map metaphor'  – maps normally having North at the top, and normally being read upright.

Comment: In all fairness to Mexico, I guess that depends if San Diego is really "all the way down."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can certainly be used, though it can be interpreted in at least a couple of ways depending on context.

To the basic statement

> I drove from Los Angeles to San Diego.

we add *down*, indicating a direction, and *[all the way](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/all+the+way#way_1__208)* adds that you drove the entire distance.

But *all the way* can also be used to emphasize the difficulty or extremity of effort to accomplish a task. Depending on context, then, one could simply be stating a fact about the morning's activity, or complaining about having to drive almost three hours— or about having to leave Los Angeles for the likes of mere San Diego.

> May I have a cookie, or are you going to make me go all the way across the street to the café?

*Down* is not always equivalent to *south*, regardless of map orientation; see *[Do I travel “up” or “down” to London from north of the city?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/do-i-travel-up-or-down-to-london-from-north-of-the-city)* and *[Does “coming down” mean “traveling south”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119482/does-coming-down-mean-traveling-south)*. While the "away from the center" sense of *down* is not common in American usage (heading *out* is usual), that would be an Angeleno's perception of the trip. And San Diego is not only south of Los Angeles, but [downcurrent](http://www.utsandiego.com/documents/2011/jun/20/california-current-ecosystem/) and [downwind](http://articles.latimes.com/1990-08-11/local/me-120_1_san-diego-exceeded-air-quality-standards) of it as well.

Comment: Is it correct to say, "I came all the way to visit you."

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly acceptable.

I regularly take the train all the way up to Edinburgh from London.  Then I might get a bus all the way down to Brighton.

The coast-to coast cycle route goes all the way across England from Whitehaven to Tynemouth.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it acceptable but many people use "all the way down" when they didn't really go down (on a map).  If you would listen to my friends talk, you may think we live on the north pole.