# Why do Americans go 'downtown' whilst people in the UK go 'up town'?

Tags: american-english, british-english

People in London, who live in the suburbs, may tell you they work 'up town', meaning in the City or the West End.

In other large cities in Britain, Birmingham, Manchester, Leeds etc., I think people who earn their living in the City Centre (equivalent to Downtown with capital D) will say casually that they work 'in town'. I think I'm right when I say that only Londoners go 'up town'.

So where did the idea of 'Downtown' come from?

Comment: The Charlotte CBD is "Uptown," though that is simply the historic name for the neighborhoods, like Chicago's "Loop" or San Francisco's "Financial District." Other American cities also have "uptown" districts outside the CBD as well; I wonder if any British cities have "downtown" quarters.

Comment: @choster 'Downtown' is quintessentially American, which isn't to say the term is not used here. (Not least by Petula Clark in her 1960s upbeat song of that name.) It is used by hotels, travel companies etc to assist American tourists, but apart from that you don't hear it much.

Comment: In Chicago there is a neighborhood called "Uptown". Endlessly confusing for a native New Yorker, for whom "Uptown" is a Manhattan-centric synonym for "North-ish".

Comment: 'Going up town' was certainly common in Oldham, at least, 50 years ago. It is still used – there is a Google reference involving Glasgow.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would that have referred to the centre of Oldham, to Manchester, or to London? Living in a village north of Norwich, people would and still do 'go into the City' if they have anything special to buy. These expressions are very peculiar to localities in Britain.

Comment: From the outlying districts (eg Hollinwood, Chadderton) to Oldham centre. (Hollinwood and Chadderton are now subsumed into greater Oldham.) We'd probably have talked about 'going down to Manchester' as the direction is vaguely southwards. No mention of 'town' with Manchester. I think 'up town' was always used as a directional or locative directly after a link or travel verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And presumably you went 'down to London'. It is interesting that in Norfolk, people went, and still go, 'up to London'. But I think that is due to the fact that north Norfolk, despite its being further north than Birmingham and much of the Midlands, is, culturally speaking, a county of the south. And I think perhaps 'going up to London' is a southern idiom.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting also about no mention of 'town' with Manchester. In Burnage the other day I heard someone speak of 'in town'meaning the City centre. Again with Norfolk, if going to London we might have asked 'What time does that train get into town'. London is both a city and a town, depending on context.

Comment: When it comes to maps and navigation, many people think there's no added value from using North for what could quite easily have been referred to as Up. I've always understood Up-town and Down-town as a simpleton's substitute for North or South of the current location. We (in Australia) also have "come up" and "come down" basically mirroring the same idea. We also don't say starboard or port side when on a boat with ordinary people when right and left will do just fine.

Comment: @Sam But I always think of you as 'Down Under'.

Comment: @WS2 sweet dreams!

Comment: Related (especially some of the answers): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23545/8019

Comment: New York, New York, it's a wonderful town: the Bronx is Up and the Battery's Down;  the people ride in a hole in the ground.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller: Confuses Chicagoans in NYC who wonder where exactly uptown is.

Comment: Anywhere I've lived uptown meant roughly north, downtown--roughly south. Similar to how you go "out west" and "back east" in America. Though that bit is likely based on manifest destiny and all of that. :D

Comment: "People in London, who live in the suburbs, may tell you they work 'up town', meaning in the City or the West End." That's ***INCREDIBLY STRANGE***.  I've never heard anyone say "up town" like that!!!  You might be going up to Cambridge, but I've never heard the words "up" and "town" used in conjunction that way, regarding any aspect of London or anything in Britain.  Experiences differ I guess, maybe it's a regional thing.  (ie, per different areas of London)

Comment: @JoeBlow Where have you lived in London? It is the sort of thing that people who live in say Wimbledon, or Croydon, might say indicating that they didn't work in any of their local towns but *up town* i.e. the City or the West End. No one says *Downtown* in Britain except Petula Clarke (now aged 83), when singing the song of that name.

Comment: In Ireland we say going "to town"/"into town". Almost never "downtown", which is considered faux and pretentious, although here is a rare example [Live in downtown Dublin](http://www.irishtimes.com/life-and-style/homes-and-property/live-in-downtown-dublin-1.1148273)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Citing [*Downtown: Its Rise and Fall, 1880-1950*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Downtown.html?id=RiCKdmZJBFsC) by Robert M. Fogelson, Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downtown):

> The term is thought to have been coined in New York City, where it was in use by the 1830s to refer to the original town at the southern tip of the island of Manhattan. As the town of New York grew into a city, the only direction it could grow on the island was toward the north, proceeding upriver from the original settlement (the "up" and "down" terminology in turn came from the customary map design in which up was north and down was south). Thus, anything north of the original town became known as "uptown" (Upper Manhattan), while the original town (which was also New York's only major center of business at the time) became known as "downtown" (Lower Manhattan).
>
> During the late 19th century, the term was gradually adopted by cities across the United States and Canada to refer to the historical core of the city (which was most often the same as the commercial heart of the city). Notably, it was not included in dictionaries as late as the 1880s. But by the early 1900s, *downtown* was clearly established as the proper term in American English for a city's central business district.

Comment: That is very interesting, it having begun with New York. It also confirms the American tendency (others may disagree) to homogenise their society. Notwithstanding the highly diverse origins of America's population, I find people's speech and social values widely consistent across the country.

Comment: @WS2 - I would attribute it more to the fact that most major US cities outside the east coast didn't *become* major cities until the latter half of the 19th century, populated by westward migration from cities like New York. The new settlers brought their speech patterns with them, some of which took hold in the new location. (I suppose this may help explain some of the homogeneity you perceive.)

Comment: @WS2 The consistency of American English is in large part a side effect of high levels of internal migration (declining sharply since 1990 or so, but still showing about 1 in 7 households moving house every year; each American moves around 12 times over a lifetime). The mass media of course had a hand over most of the 20th century. Greater tolerance of regional distinctions (e.g. television shows featuring people with Southern accents are rather more common now than 30 years ago) and declining mobility may see a resurgence of locally identified quirks of AmE.

Comment: In Britain generally we go 'up' to anywhere of importance. When I lived in Norfolk as a child, although it was north of the capital, we always went 'up' to London. People would talk about what happens 'up London', often with disdain! People are also said to be 'up in court' when arraigned. Students go 'up' to university. My sense is that this same idea is customary across Europe. Joseph and Mary went up to Jerusalem to be taxed (didn't they?) . So in the light of this cultural omnipresence of 'up' being to a place of importance in Western society, the American 'downtown' seems remarkable.

Comment: @choster - Interesting comments, and yes, internal migration was very, very high, but the statistics don't take into account moving within an area, e.g. from one neighborhood to a better one within the same geographical area (a common occurrence to put kids into a better school system as incomes rise.) As to going to another city, many of us just say, *go to*. "Want to go to NY this weekend? Go to Philly?" But downtown is definitely downtown.

Comment: @Susan But even on measures such as moves across state lines or county lines or arbitrary distances (e.g. 150km), Americans were historically far more likely to move than any other country not facing war or disaster. Of course, that's a national average; Pew says about 4 in 10 Americans lives in the same county he or she was born in, and the younger and more highly educated move far more often than older and less educated.

Comment: Philadelphia is an exception, which in a way is evidence for this theory.  Philadelphia was once upon a time a larger city than New York, and its central business district isn't "downtown", it's "Center City".  This suggests that the name got established before the New York influence mattered.

Comment: "Up" can mean "upstream" (likelier for Upper Manhattan, which is northeast of the Battery, not due north), "north" (for widespread mapping practices), "uphill," and various forms of higher status. Abundant streams and hills in many of the regions of America first settled by the British might account for wider use of geographic uses of "up" in place names here than socioeconomic ones. By the way, not all Chicagoans refer to the entire CBD as "the Loop," but restrict it somewhat: south of the Chicago River, east of the South Branch, and north of Roosevelt Road.

Comment: "Up" means "North". "Down" means "South"
/american

Comment: @WS2 As far as the Bible mentioning people going 'up' to Jerusalem, the meaning is literal. Jerusalem is located on a mountain range. To get there, one must quite literally go up. Its elevation is around 2,500' above sea level, whereas much of Israel is at or even below sea level. The Dead Sea's elevation is _negative_ 1,400 feet, for example. The Sea of Galilee's elevation is -700 feet.

Answer (score 5):

It would seem to me, from reading the responses, and from thinking further, that the history of the development of New York City played a big part in the notion of 'Downtown'. It is a  word that generally-speaking sounds foreign to British ears, but which is employed by the travel industry in the UK for the benefit of tourists.

'Downtown', as I understand it, has two important senses. 'Downtown Minneapolis' is what in Britain we would call the 'City Centre of Minneapolis'.

Where Americans say they are 'going down town', we (especially Londoners) will say we are going 'up town'. In other British cities people may say 'I'm going into town', or 'I'm going in to the City Centre'. But usage across Britain is highly peculiar to local circumstances, and varies greatly from place to place. Also the whole question of what is a city and what is a town, and in what circumstance we refer to Birmingham as a city and in what circumstances we say 'going into town (meaning Birmingham centre) ' is highly nuanced and particular to places.

I would also be interested to learn exactly what is meant by the American term 'Central Business District'. In the case of London, I am never sure if this would mean the City of London, where the Bank of England, the Stock Exchange, and the whole panoply of financial institutions are housed, or the shopping area around Oxford Street.

Comment: As I understand it, "Central Business District" would mean where the large business offices and financial institutions are. So for London, the equivalent probably would be "City of London". (Although London is large enough it may have several areas which count as "central business districts".)

Answer (score 5):

............................................................................................................................................................

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is an appealing explanation, it makes sense but as I am not American I cannot be certain if this holds. Could you please provide a reference which backs up your hypothesis?

Comment: Another reason for uptown/downtown on US river cities is that when the city has hills rising behind the riverfront, "uptown" is away from the banks at a higher elevation and avoids flooding.  Thus the other way is 'downtown' and the business district.

Comment: **WHERE IS THIS REFERENCE FROM**?  It's truly interesting, but it could be total crap.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess probably because the city center was either located South of their present location, or because the location was actually physically low in elevation.  A good example of this is when the dense part of the city "the down town part", is located in a valley, while most of the housing is on the foothills.

Answer (score 1):

**Town** is directly related to the word **down** and originally meant *enclosed land* or *fortress* which, for obvious security reasons, would be built *up* on high ground where the surrounding area would be *down*.

(Compare related words *sand* **dune**, the surname **Dunhill** 'Hill-hill', and the meaning of **downs** for hilly land: *Barnhart Dictionary of Etymology*.)

For the purposes of transportation and trade, a town's business district would naturally be located *down* near a body of water, such as an ocean, lake, or river. As the population grew, the inhabitants would often build further *uphill* and away from the water--the commercial center.  Although Americans may have copied the 'Manhattan model' to describe their own towns, the use of **downtown** to mean the central business district would have made perfect sense at the time. (see Wikipedia 'downtown')

From my experience living in cities in Ohio, Oregon, Alaska, and New Jersey, the word *uptown* seems to be extremely rare, with the exception of Manhattan, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding seeing London as 'up'.**

This is a UK railway convention where London is (almost) always 'up', geographical directions notwithstanding. (cite: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_directions#United_Kingdom))

(c.f. in Downton Abbey, where they talk about going 'up' to London, despite going south from Yorkshire.)

(I'm not so sure about the reasoning given in the wikipedia. It is claimed that it's from early lines going between 'upland' mines and 'downcountry' ports. The reason I have heard is that early timetables always had London at the top. This was then repeated by Bradshaw and became universal.)

Comment: Sure, you go "up" to London.  But I've never heard anyone say "up town".  I'm really surprised everyone else didn't mention this.  Obviously it's some weird thing.

Comment: @JoeBlow Are you able to articulate more clearly what you mean by *weird*? Ghostly apparitions are *weird* - I'm sure you didn't mean something like that!

Answer (score 0):

Noting this line in the OP ...

> "... City Centre (equivalent to Downtown with capital D)"

note that "downtown" and "uptown" have no connection to city "center"

these two words are today **adjectives** that mean a certain type of style.

Definitions:

> Downtown: an "artistic", "bohemian" style.  for example, the "artistic", "bohemian" expensive part of a city center
>
> Uptown: a "straightlaced", "formal" style. for example, the straightlaced expensive part of the city center

The epitome of this is of course in New York ... downtown is SoHo, Tribeca and so on (central / expensive / bohemian).  Uptown is Park Avenue and so on (central / expensive / straightlaced).

(Both parts are fully "central", they are both the densest parts of the urban center.  If you're in say Connecticut, and you're about to head to Manhattan, you wouldn't say "you're going uptown" nor would you say "you're going downtown". You'd say "I'm going in to the city" (or perhaps "I'm going to Manhattan"); someone may ask "where are you going in the city?" and you may answer "I'm going uptown" or "I'm going downtown".)

They're, today, just adjectives.

For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCuMWrfXG4E

[image]

(Or indeed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPf0YbXqDm0

[image] )

A new coffee shop (anywhere - in Sydney) might be described as having an "uptown vibe" (stainless steel, etc) or a "downtown feel" (bohemian).  Andy Warhol - downtown.  Donald Trump - uptown.

This usage surely originates **with NYC becoming a general cultural referent**, at a guess **in the 1970s**?  (The distinction between SoHo, Park Avenue, was in place by then.)

Answer (score -1):

Spending the 1st 32 years of my life living all across America, I would venture that all the preceding answers are a factor. Many of the "original" town hubs were both lower elevations and to some degree south, the perception "downtown" implying work, toil, business, while "uptown" implies leisure $$$ etc. And of course something I distinctly realized after I left, the American persistence to differentiate themselves from everyone else. They use NTSC everyone else PAL, they dove into the water everyone else dived, 120 v/60 Hz vs. 220/50 Hz, altering the spelling of many words, grounded vs. earthed electricity.

Comment: It is all to do with the notion, now referred to by some historians as 'American Exceptionalism'. It is the idea from the start held by Americans that their country was in some way a special case, and should be regarded as 'exceptional'. Type those two  words into Amazon and see how many books come up. I particularly refer you to the works of Trevor McCrisken.,

Comment: @WS2: I seem to remember from a recent read that American Exceptionalism was a notion quipped by Lenin. The notion was pejorative (as in, the US is the exception where communism won't go mainstream) until the USSR fell. Only then did it get picked up by US media and earn the current positive connotation.

Comment: @Denis My only advice is to read McCrisken.

Comment: etymology, you're thinking of Stalin.  the origin is mixed, it seems to be more of a "popular simplification" that Stalin "invented" it.  need only click to wik ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_exceptionalism#Etymology